# jQuery-Mobile: Page does not load completely when swiped to

Tags: jquery-mobile

Today I prepared some PHP pages with jQuery-Mobile. It should enable for swiping from one page to another.

In general the swiping works but there is one problem: When I've swiped to a new page swiping doesn't work on that page first. Only when I reload the page it works again. The page source before reloading is OK.

It seems to me that not all inclusions are executed when I have swiped to a new page. How can this be fixed? E.g.: [Ref link](http://www.ulrichbangert.de/orchid/tropische/2012-12_Paphiopedilum-Hybride.php)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var urlup, urlleft, urlright;
    $('img').on('dragstart', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    });
    $('img').each(function (i) {
        if (this.src.indexOf("buttonup.png") >= 0) {
            urlup = this.parentNode.href;
            this.id = "buttonup";
        } else if (this.src.indexOf("buttonleft.png") >= 0) {
            urlleft = this.parentNode.href;
            this.id = "buttonleft"
        } else if (this.src.indexOf("buttonright.png") >= 0) {
            urlright = this.parentNode.href;
            this.id = "buttonright";
        } else {};
    });
    //$.mobile.loadPage(urlup);
    //$.mobile.loadPage(urlleft);
    //$.mobile.loadPage(urlright);
    $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("load", urlup);
    $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("load", urlleft);
    $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("load", urlright);
    $(document).on("swipeup", function () {
        $.mobile.changePage(urlup);
    });
    $(document).on("swipeleft", function () {
        $.mobile.changePage(urlright);
    });
    $(document).on("swiperight", function () {
        $.mobile.changePage(urlleft, {
            reverse: true
        });
    });
    $("#buttonup").click(function () {
        $.mobile.changePage(urlup, {
            transition: "slideup"
        });
    });
    $("#buttonleft").click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
    $("#buttonleft").click(function () {
        $.mobile.changePage(urlleft, {
            reverse: true
        });
    });
    $("#buttonright").click(function () {
        $.mobile.changePage(urlright);
    });
});
```

Comment: In the meantime I read the manual of pageload and switched to the load function of the container object. Also updated to Version 1.4.2. Unfortunately this did not fix the problem

Comment: Furtheron I noticed that the buttons work fine. The problem occurs only when swiping. Can't understand this as the same function is used for changing the page.

Comment: You should add sample code. And use jQuery 1.9 with jQM 1.4

Comment: This is the first part of my code:      $(document).on("mobileinit", function() {
          $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "slide";
      });The sedond part is in this file: http://www.ulrichbangert.de/js/mobile.js (wasn't able to format the code. Are there no code tags?)

Comment: There's no special tags, just leave at least "four" spaces before code.

Comment: Updated to jQuery 1.9.1. Problem is the same.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I was able to fix this problem: I used the document-ready-event and this one is not fired when jQuery Mobile loads a new page. Thus the javascript code that binds the swiping events was not executed. I had to use JMs pageinit event instead. After fixing some other problems swiping works fine on my pages now:
http://www.ulrichbangert.de/orchid/odm_rawdonjester.php
Best regards - Ulrich